# Ogre3D with CEGUI

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, game-engine, ogre3d, cegui

I'm trying to make a program with ogre3D and CEGUI.

I'm compiling my project thank's to this cmake:
http://pastebin.com/idCLSwyi

And another cmake to find CEGUI:
http://pastebin.com/X8zKJGt1

All seems good when I cmake the project.

But when i try to make, I got this error:

```
undefined reference to `CEGUI::OgreRenderer::bootstrapSystem(int)'
```

My includes:

```
#include <CEGUI/CEGUI.h>
#include <CEGUI/RendererModules/Ogre/Renderer.h>
```

I'm using CEGUI 0.8.6 and Ogre 1.10.

Has anyone ever had this error ? Or may be someone know how to solve it ?
Thank's in advance.

Comment: You might have a better chance getting an answer in the [Ogre Addons CEGUI forums](http://www.ogre3d.org/addonforums/viewforum.php?f=34&sid=0e340cdf4a2b44f7f8ed128eb6ed8bb9). The CEGUI developers are mods there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the solution:

I forgot to add : `${CEGUI_OgreRenderer_LIBRARIES}` at this line:

```
target_link_libraries(OgreApp ${OGRE_LIBRARIES} ${OIS_LIBRARIES} ${OGRE_Overlay_LIBRARIES} ${CEGUI_LIBRARIES}))
```